What is an example where the result of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion removes cv-qualifiers?
Under Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion the C++23 standard says ([conv.lval]#1, emphasis mine):

A glvalue of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted to a prvalue.44
If T is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed.
If T is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of T.
Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is T.45

Could you give an example, where this happens?
i.e:

starting with a glvalue of type T which is a non-class,
lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is executed, and
we end up in a prvalue of type std::remove_cvref_t<T>


Check RVO and NRVO.

For example:
const int i = 0;
/*const*/ int j = i;

i is a non-class type const-qualified glvalue. In order to initialize j, a standard conversion sequence from this glvalue to a prvalue of type int is required. The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is chosen and your particular case applies.
The same applies e.g. when using the built-in arithmetic operators on i, etc. Whether there is a qualifier on j doesn't matter. They are ignored and the target of the conversion sequence is the unqualified type.
Also note that non-class type prvalues are never cv-qualified, so it wouldn't make sense for the conversion to not strip the qualifier.

Is there a way to verify with a C++ program, that the result of that conversion is indeed an rvalue, and not an lvalue?

@Dr.Gut The question is tautological. Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion produces an rvalue by definition. If it didn't, then it wouldn't have been an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

@RaymondChen: In other words, is there a way to verify, that an lvalue-to-rvalue and not an lvalue-to-lvalue conversion happened? j can be initialized from both, so this code snippet does not distinguish the two.

@Dr.Gut "j can be initialized from both" is only true in the sense that the initializer expression on the right-hand side by itself may be either a lvalue or a rvalue, but in order to initialize an object of scalar type, there must (almost) always be conversion to a rvalue per https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16.9 first. There is nothing to differentiate. There doesn't exist any category of lvalue-to-lvalue conversions that could apply to form this conversion sequence to an rvalue.

@Dr.Gut You can make the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion "visible" by adding constexpr to the declaration and replacing 0 in the initialization of i by e.g. argc of main. It will then fail compilation for the initialization not being a constant expression. The only way this could not be a constant expression is by there being an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an object that is not usable in constant expressions (i.e. i), per https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.9. Potentially the compiler will even tell you that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is the problem.

@user17732522: Your reasoning is based on the standard. I don't know the standard, and to me everything is explicable without referring to lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. The last example (demo) has a simpler explanation: argc is not a constant expression, while the initializer of i has to be one. That's why it's rejected. You see, to me the notion of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion feels mysterious. Even in this example I see no evidence, that any lvalue had to be converted to an rvalue. I can't catch that conversion anywhere (except in the standard).

@Dr.Gut An lvalue's result refers to some object. An object can, at any given point in the program execution, hold a specific value out of a set of values permitted for the type. A prvalue's result on the other hand is one such value itself, without any reference to an object. A lvalue-to-rvalue conversion represents the operation that is required to obtain a value from the lvalue referring to an object. In most cases that means reading the value that the object holds at runtime. But e.g. in compile-time contexts, it instead is the action of substituting with the compile-time known value.

@Dr.Gut Regarding the example: Of course it is intuitively clear that the variable can't be constexpr because it's initial value can't be computed at compile-time. But that must be formalized somehow in the standard. And the way that this is done is exactly via the notion of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. It is exactly application of an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an object whose value isn't known at compile-time that makes it impossible to perform the computation of the initial value at compile-time, because it would imply reading the value that the object holds at runtime.

@user17732522: Thank you for the answer, and the explanations afterwards. In the meantime the question was closed by a C++, a C#/C++ and a Delphi/C++ developer. I still think, the question is valid to ask, and the C++ standard could have more examples itself.
